# how to scroll group and child after expend expendable list-view in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"

    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
                android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"

                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

this is my code :

```
 expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                groupName = expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition);
                listtG1 = ExpandableListDataPump.getData().get(groupName);
                Log.d("ListSize", String.valueOf(listtG1.size()));



            }
        });


        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                groupName = expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition);
                listtG1 = ExpandableListDataPump.getData().get(groupName);

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        groupName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();

                Log.d("ListSize", String.valueOf(listtG1.size()));


                if (listtG1.size() == 1 && listtG1.get(0).equals(groupName)) {


                    return true;
                } else


                    return false;

            }
        });


        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                childName = listtG1.get(childPosition);
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        childName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();


                return false;
            }
        });
```

this is my code for expendable  list-view to print data when  group is not expend or if group expend and child contain only one data  then its look like this which is correct .

[image]

but when i expend  and child contaion more than 2 or 3 data then other group becomes hide like this [image]

i want when practical group expend then other should also display and it should scrolled with child and group please tell me or suggest me how to fix it .